# Thermal transport in a rotating fluid

Tags: rotation, kinetic-theory

Suppose that we have a rotating fluid with nonzero heat conductivity and the rotation is uniform and stationary. The centrifugal force should then be compensated by the gradient of temperature (assume for simplicity that chemical potential is constant). Now, it is clear that there is no heat current induced by this gradient (or at least I think so) because if we go to a frame of reference rotating with the fluid then the gradient of temperature would be screened by the "gravitational force" (which is the centrifugal force), but I just don't understand how to explain this in terms of the laboratory frame. Is there some generalization of Fourier's Law for the flowing fluid, maybe? Or I am just missing something in my reasoning. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Is your rotating fluid "self-gravitating"? namely: are you considering a fluid planet/star? Is the body in thermal equilibrium?

Comment: Yeah, thermal equilibrium is assumed but the "real" gravitational effects are irrelevant. The fluid can even be non-relativistic. Suppose we just have the some water in the rotating cylinder.

Comment: So, if this is the case, I do not understant why there should be a thermal gradient. In a rotating bucket filled with fluid, the "centrifugal force" is counterbalanced by the pressure (created by the fact that the free surface has a meniscus, and it's not flat).

Comment: Of course, but we can rewrite the gradient of the pressure using that $dp = s dT + n d\mu$ (here $s$ is entropy density and $n$ is a charge density and $\mu$ is a corresponding chemical potential). If we assume $\mu = const$ then the gradient of pressure should be due to the gradient of temperature.

Comment: But why do you want to assume constant chemical potential and not constant temperature, is there a reason for that? moreover: if the surface is free, the gradient of pressure is just given by the fact that the surface is not flat: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189181/shape-of-a-rotating-fluid-surface

Comment: We can keep $\mu = const$ just for simplicity, for example we can say that the fluid is an ideal conductor and there is no external electromagnetic fields. Anyway, if the electric conductivity would be finite and there could be a gradient of the chemical potential, the question would stand then why is there no electric current? Also, I am not trying to say that there is no pressure gradient, the question is, how can I explain that this gradient does not produce any transport and is there a general criterion for that.

Comment: The criterion is: write down the hydrodynamic equations (e.g. Navier Stokes or whatever describes your fluid, mass conservation and energy transport equation). Impose that all the temporal derivatives are zero. Take into account for the Coriolis force. Solve for the stationary solution. Typically the stationary solution allows for pressure gradients, it is not homogeneous.