# Rotation of liquid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, rotational-dynamics, flow, vortex

How do we derive velocity of liquid in tube rotating about fixed axis? I've tried deriving but I can only think of equating centrifugal force and surface tension that pulls the liquid back.

Comment: This phenomenon is known as $Taylor-Couette$ flow and basically involves two cylinders, with some fluid in the annular region between them. One of the cylinders is made to rotate, causing the liquid to rotate, like a vortex. You can look it up on the internet now.

Comment: Here is a video link, that might help you - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSK_V--6G9c)

Comment: Do you meen a tube or a larger thing like a cylinder rotating around its axe? After some time the liquid will have the same angular velocity and the inner surface will be a parabola.

Comment: See another answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189181/shape-of-a-rotating-fluid-surface).